# Unable to set connection type in Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager

Tags: android, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

For the *Visual Studio Android Emulator* I have to set the internet connection as a *Virtual Switch*. But I keep getting an error. This is what happens when I change the Virtual Switch of Windows Phone Emulator to my Physical network:

[image: Virtual Switch Manager]

By default it's set to Internal Network, when I select External network and my physical network controller it gives the error above.

The error message is (sorry my PC is installed in Dutch):

> **Error with changes for properties of virtual switch**
>
> There occured an error while adding the connection for the virtual ethernet switch.
>
> The external Ethernet-adapter Qualcomm Atheros already has a
>   connection with the Microsoft-protocol for virtual switches.
>
> **(^)** Hide details          [ Close ]